# Same Random Numbers Every Time

Tags: r

I'm running a script from the command line via 
`R CMD BATCH script.in.R script.out.R &`

I have the following line, which picks 12 random row ids and sorts them:

```
test.index<-sort(sample(1:nrow(recoded),12))
```

It spits out the same 12 numbers every time if I don't change the script. If I change it a little bit (change a label or a string or anything) then the numbers are different...I need them to be different every time!

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same behaviour occur if you run the script in an interactive R session?

Comment: And just to be sure, you do have more than 12 rows in `recoded`, don't you?  Otherwise that line of code will just spit out 1 to 12.

Comment: Also try changing the script to *just that line* to confirm that the problem is really elsewhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds weird. What's the rest of the script doing? If it calls (or some other function it calls) `set.seed`, that would explain things, but since you say changing (what I assume to be) the *data*, that would imply that the seed is set to some hash of your dataset?! Or is it if you change the *script* in any way?

Anyway, you can insert a line like `rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())` before your call to `sample`, which should reset the seed to a random one...

Another way is to generate a unique seed yourself. Here's one way based on time and process id.

```
 set.seed( as.integer((as.double(Sys.time())*1000+Sys.getpid()) %% 2^31) )
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably have a call to `set.seed()` in there. Here is an example:

```
$ Rscript -e 'runif(4)'      
[1] 0.639716 0.976892 0.486573 0.525979

$ Rscript -e 'runif(4)'
[1] 0.516927 0.951013 0.931756 0.741650

$ Rscript -e 'runif(4)'
[1] 0.159682 0.314798 0.356476 0.584326

$ Rscript -e 'set.seed(42); runif(4)'
[1] 0.914806 0.937075 0.286140 0.830448

$ Rscript -e 'set.seed(42); runif(4)'
[1] 0.914806 0.937075 0.286140 0.830448

$
```

The first three all differ, then I enforce a common seed and *presto* the numbers are identical.

Also, `Rscript` is nicer than `R CMD BATCH`.

Comment: It's less probable, but this can also be caused by not resetting the random seed in compiled code that's being called.

Comment: I'm a bit confused (excuse my novice), everything seems backwards from what I wanted. By default yours were random, and then you had to do something to make them the same......I'm confused..I hadn't set a seed yet my numbers are always the same!

Comment: @user964373  Dirk is illustrating that there may be a call to `set.seed()` in your code.  If you remove it, you should get values that differ on each run.

Comment: Either you *do* have a `set.seed()` enforcing your numbers to be the same (so you need to remove it), or you could at least try to enforce randomness by adding something like `set.seed(as.numeric(Sys.time())`. Either way you *have to look at your code* as I showed that R *by default uses a different seed on startup*.

Comment: OOOOH I see. Gotcha. I can't find a set.seed in my code but maybe there is one in one of the libraries I'm using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have not loaded any previous workspace. If you have, the previous seed is also loaded, thus giving you the same results.

Comment: This would go as comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem and it was because I was loading a Workspace in which the seed had been set. The way to get it back to normal is...

set.seed(Null)

note that setting the seed to something random will not work, since the random number  generated will always be the same, and therefore the new seed. But the above works.