# R set.seed does not produce consistent results

Tags: r, random

I am using a main R function to call a series of R functions from different scripts. In order to reproduce results, I `set.seed` in the beginning of my main script. In the code, `sample()` function to randomly select a couple of rows from a `dataframe` in `function_8`, and `rand()` in `function_6`. So a simple workflow is like below:

```
### Main R Function
library(dplyr)
set.seed(111)

### Begin calling other R scripts
output_1 <- function_1(...)
...
output_10 <- function_10(...)

### End Main R Function
```

Recently, I realized that if I make changes to my `function_9` which does not contain any randomization. Random numbers generated from in `function_8` changes. For example,

- `sample()` in `function_8` will get Row 2, 15, 23, 50, 54 before updating `function_9`.
- `sample()` in `function_8` will get Row 23, 44, 50, 95, 98 after updating `function_9`
- However, results can be reproduced by starting a new R session.

So, I am wondering if anyone can give me some suggestions on how to properly `set.seed` in this situation? THX in advance!

#### Update

Per a deleted comment, I change the seed number to 123, which produces a set of consistent results. But I appreciate if someone can provide any in-depth explanation!

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example, with sample function_1 to 10 (or 6, 8 and 9 at least)?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the series 111 is just have same character which doesn't change the function 8, you maybe want to generate a time based random seed, Here is [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810338/same-random-numbers-every-time), that may help you by using system time.